# How to escape ampersand & in password in maven settings.xml

Tags: xml, maven, maven-2

I have been given an ldap password which contains ampersand `&` . I am trying to use it in settings.xml and getting parsing issues. Till now I have tried

1. replace `&` with `&amp;`
2. Replace password with `<![CDATA[my&password]]>`

Neither of these approaches worked. Can't pass it in command line as it is in too many places.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would encrypt passwords all the time..never clear password in any file.. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

Comment: Both approaches should work; if they didn't, then you need to explain in more detail exactly what you did and exactly how it failed.